# Rails destroys existing has_one child before raising validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a model relationship like this:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :child, dependent: destroy
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

The foreign key is in the `childs` table:

```
t.belongs_to :parent, index: { unique: true }, foreign_key: true
```

In the `childs_controller`, I have a `create` method from the route `POST /parents/<id>/childs`:

```
def create
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])

  @child = @parent.create_child! params[:child]

  render json: @child, status: 200
end
```

When I first POST data to this controller, the child model is created accordingly. When I POST child data to the controller *again*, it throws a validation error, since the parent ID is already taken. This is expected. However, the existing child is destroyed at the same time. This means that when I POST data for a third time, a new child is created.

The corresponding log where the child is deleted looks like this:

```
Child Exists? (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "childs" WHERE "childs"."parent_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["parent_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_3
Child Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "childs".* FROM "childs" WHERE "childs"."parent_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["parent_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_3
Child Destroy (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM "childs" WHERE "childs"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
 (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_3

ERROR: Validation failed: Parent has already been taken
```

I can work around this by wrapping the creation in a transaction:

```
Parent.transaction do
  @child = @parent.create_child! params[:child]
end
```

But I don't understand why this suddently works.

So:

- Why is the existing child model destroyed when trying to create a new one (in a *has one* relationship) is invalid?
- Why does wrapping it in a transaction prevent that behavior?